# awk – how to put a regexp in a variable if I want to use it within if/else logic?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, command-line, awk

When I apply this code:

```
gawk '{ if ($0 ~ /cat|dog/) {
print "animal" }
else if ($0 ~ /[[:digit:]]+/) {
print "number" }
else { print "unknown" } }' path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

to this input:

```
100
cat
200
something
dog
```

I see the desired output:

```
number
animal
number
unknown
animal
```

Nice. But when I use this code:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {animals = /cat|dog/; 
digits = /[[:digit:]]+/ }
{ if ($0 ~ animals) {
print "animal" }
else if ($0 ~ digits) {
print "number" }
else { print "unknown" } }' path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

I see this output:

```
animal
unknown
animal
unknown
unknown
```

What's going on? Really weird and unpredictable!

Comment: if you use `/` as regex delimiter than you must use `~` symbol while assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store and reuse regex like this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {animals = "cat|dog"; digits = "[[:digit:]]+" }
{ if ($0 ~ animals) {
   print "animal" }
else if ($0 ~ digits) {
print "number" }
else { print "unknown" } }' path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

i.e. don't use regex delimiter while storing it in variable.